# Impossible SELF_REFERENCE error when merging cases

Tags: error, merge, process, case-comment

I have a process (built with process builder), which triggers on case comments that are created (not modified). There are no triggers, workflows or flows on case comments.

I merge two cases, neither of which has a case comment. The merge is successful: Salesforce tells me as much and only one case is left. However, I also get a mail with a FlowApplication error:

> SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER: Object 5002500000xxxxxxxx is currently in
> a merge operation, therefore a trigger can not update it.

According to the mail, the process that concerns newly created case comments is responsible for the error.

But there are no case comments at all!

It's a minor nuisance, of course, as the merge itself was successful, but apparently not everything is as it should be. Is there any way to prevent the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I tried next, was to merge two cases that had case comments, one each. The resulting case had three case comments! Two obviously from the merged cases as well as a new one, created by the standard Salesforce merge operation. Its contents: "Case X has been merged with case Y".

Ah, so a case comment was created and my process was indeed fired. Apparently the actions of the process are not allowed while being in a merge operation.

So what I am doing now, in the process that handles new case comments: a new first step filters out these merge comments. I do that by checking the CommentBody for "has been merged with case". This is a bad solution, obviously:

- If Salesforce changes their phrasing, this does not work anymore.
- Should a user make a comment that accidentally contains this text, then the intended functionality will not fire.

Any suggestions for a cleaner solution are welcome, of course!

Comment: You should be able to just filter out any comments that have a created date greater or equal to the last modified date of the case.